# numpy advanced indexing feature or bug?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

numpy advanced indexing anomalies. I encountered this while working on an assignment for CS 190.1X. Took a while for me to grasp the dimensions.

```
>>> a = np.ndarray([3,3],int)
>>> a[:,1]
array([-1,0,0])
>>> a[:,[1]]
array([[-1],[0],[0]])
```

is this a feature or a bug ? :)

Comment: The simple answer is the indexing with a scalar removes a dimension.  Indexing with a single element list preserves the dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a[:, 1]` is an example of [basic slicing and indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

`a[:, [1]]` is an example of [combining advanced and basic indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing). The `:` is a basic slice, but the `[1]` triggers advance integer indexing.

Since the advanced indexes are all next to each other, [the rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) for combining advance and basic indexing say,

> the dimensions from the advanced indexing operations are inserted into the result array at the same spot as they were in the initial array (the latter logic is what makes simple advanced indexing behave just like slicing).

Thus, the integer index, `[1]`, whose shape as an array would be `(1,)`, causes an extra dimension of the same shape to be inserted
in the result.

---

```
In [12]: a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

In [13]: a[:,1].shape
Out[13]: (3,)

In [14]: a[:,[1]].shape
Out[14]: (3, 1)

In [15]: a[:,[1,2]].shape
Out[15]: (3, 2)

In [16]: a[:,[[1,2],[0,1]]].shape
Out[16]: (3, 2, 2)
```