# Why numpy array returns oryginal array when passing array as index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I find this behaviour an utter nonsense. This happens only with numpy arrays, typical Python's arrays will just throw an error.

Let's create two arrays:

```
randomNumMatrix = np.random.randint(0,20,(3,3,3), dtype=np.int)
randRow = np.array([0,1,2], dtype=np.int)
```

If we pass an array as index to get something from another array, an original array is returned.

```
randomNumMatrix[randRow]
```

The code above returns an equivalent of randomNumMatrix. I find this unintuitive. I would expect it, not to work or at least return an equivalent of

```
randomNumMatrix[randRow[0]][randRow[1]][randRow[2]].
```

Additional observations:

A)
The code below does not work, it throws this error: IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

```
randRow = np.array([0, 1, 3], dtype=np.int)
```

B)
To my surprise, the code below works:

```
randRow = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2,0,1,2], dtype=np.int)
```

Can somebody please explain what are the advantages of this feature?
In my opinion it only creates much confusion.

Comment: This way you can fastly extract certain rows/columns from array. With python list you can do it with list comprehensions, but it is too much boilerplate code and object creation overhead for numpy where this operation is much common.

Comment: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy advanced indexing feature or bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770408/numpy-advanced-indexing-feature-or-bug)

Answer (score 0):

What is?

```
randomNumMatrix[randRow[0]][randRow[1]][randRow[2]]
```

That's not a valid Python.

In `numpy` there is a difference between

```
arr[(x,y,z)]     # equivalent to arr[x,y,z]
```

and

```
arr[np.array([x,y,z])]     # equivalent to arr[np.array([x,y,z]),:,:]
```

The tuple provides a scalar index for each dimension.  The array (or list) provides multiple indices for one dimension.

You may need to study the numpy docs on indexing, especially advanced indexing.